# How to implement proxy pattern involving async call?

Tags: java, design-patterns, asynchronous, proxy-pattern

How to implement proxy pattern involving async call?

Just for example, if I want to get something, I will first check if the object resides in memory, if it's not, then I will make http request to retrieve it (which is async call).

```
Customer customer;
customer = CustomerDAO.getCustomerByName("John");
```

and inside the CustomerDAO.getCustomerByName("John");

```
Customer getCustomerByName(String name)
{
    int age = 40;

    if (map.contains(name)) 
    {
        Customer customer = map.get(name);
        customer.age = age;
        return customer;
    }
    else
    {
        makeRequestAsnyc(name, callback);
    }
}
```

However since it's async, it breaks the flow of the program. Also any local variables in getCustomers have to be passed to callback function too. Any suggestion of implementing Proxy pattern with Async? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? (Sorry, I'm guessing about the 'Callback' class)

```
Customer getCustomerByName(String name, Callback callback)
{
    int age = 40;

    if (map.contains(name)) 
    {
        Customer customer = map.get(name);
        customer.age = age;
        callback.call(customer);
    }
    else
    {
        makeRequestAsnyc(name, callback);
    }
}
```

In general you don't want to introduce blocking methods when you have an asynch API already.

Comment: It will break the flow
`customer = CustomerDAO.getCustomerByName("John");`

Comment: @janetsmith: On the contrary, I suggest that the line of code you've typed there will break the asynch nature of the API, and isn't a good idea if you can avoid it.